# How do I structure firebase to be able to search all users by availability by date

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, nosql

I'm trying to figure out how to create a shallow firebase data structure for an app related to user availability.

Context about the app is that an employer may be looking to contract out temporary help. The app allows users/contractors to post their availability by date and region... not too concerned about region right now.

How do I structure the app so that the employer can search by date/region and see all users that have said they are available?

Assume that the users can change their availability at any time and its non-sequential. They can only say I'm available on specific list of days like:

```
pseudo code

Availability UserA: [ 03/01/2017, 03/14/2017, 04/01/2017 ] 
Availability UserB: [ 03/14/2017, 03/15/2017, 04/06/2017 ] 
Availability UserC: [ 03/01/2017, 03/14/2017, 04/07/2017 ]
```

Do I make an availability node and add users by id there and query on it or do you query all users and have an availability for each user in a user node?

I'll be using AngularFire2 by the way.

Thanks!

Comment: If employers are searching by date, then region, the simplest data model is `/AvailableContractors/$date/$region/$uid`. If they are more likely to start with a region and then a date, modeling it as `/AvailableContractors/$region/$date/$uid` allows you to get date ranges for a region (if you store dates in a lexicographically sortable format, such as `2017-03-14`).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks! I'm having a hard time picturing this. So the top node is AvailableContractors, then you have all future dates under it, then regions then the UID? I'm missing something...

Comment: Yup, that is the first option. The second option inverts regions and dates.

Comment: That's really interesting. Many users could be available on the same date... So along that path, you show all those users. I'm also assuming, you only add a new $date, once the user says they are available and remove once there are no more users available on a date.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So, every contractor needs to be able to update their availability on a view. So it might be /contractors/$uid/availablity .. How would you keep that in sync with /AvailableContractors/$region/$date/$uid? Does the multi-path update functionality work for this?

Comment: Yes. Also see my last comment to another question today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352395/firebase-sorting-filtering-with-keys-node/42352870?noredirect=1#comment71857620_42352870

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen What would you suggest the best date format to set the  node? Availability/1485907200/UID:true   where 1485907200 is an EPOCH formatted time... I would set the minutes and seconds to 0. In the long run, I may want to filter nodes by day, week or month...  Dropping the region idea and I'm going to use GeoFire to filter by radius. Return those UID keys and map it to the availability node.