# Firebase sorting/filtering with keys node

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, relationship, nosql

```
{
"places": {
    "<push-key>": {
        "name": "Company X"
    },
    "<push-key>": {
        "name": "Restaurant Y"
    }
}
"stamps": {
    "<push-key>": {
        "value": 0,
        "date": 1487344650456
    }
},
"placeStamps": {
    "<place-push-key>": {
        "<stamp-push-key-1>": true,
        "<stamp-push-key-2>": true,
        "<stamp-push-key-3>": true
    }
}
}
```

We are new to Firebase and we were wondering if there was a way to sort our stamps (node in the database) by date. Our flow goes as following:

- We retrieve the place that we want, using the places node.
- With the key of the place we retrieve the stamp keys from the placeStamps/ node.
- Then we retrieve the stamps one-by-one from the stamps node.

Is there a way to sort/filter these objects by for example the ‘date’ or ‘value’? We can’t do it client-side, because we are talking about millions of stamps.

Comment: I added a first stab below. If that is not what you're stuck at, share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To query the stamps since 24 hours ago:

```
var ref = firebase.database.ref("stamps");
var now = Date.now();
var yesterday = now - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var query = ref.orderByChild("Date").startAt(yesterday);
query.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```

If you want to retrieve the stamps for a certain place by timestamp, you have two options:

- retrieve the stamps for the place and order them by timestamp client-side. Retrieving multiple items is not as slow as you may expect, since Firebase pipelines the requests. See [Speed up fetching posts for my social network app by using query instead of observing a single event repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).
- add the timestamp to the stamp key for each place:

  ```
  placeStamps": {
    "<place-push-key>": {
      "<stamp-push-key-1>": 1487344650456,
      "<stamp-push-key-2>": 1487344650457,
      "<stamp-push-key-3>": 1487344650458
    }
  }
  ```

  Now you can get the stamps for a place by timestamp with:

  ```
  var ref = firebase.database.ref("placeStamps").child("<place-push-key>");
  var now = Date.now();
  var yesterday = now - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  var query = ref.orderByValue().startAt(yesterday);
  ```

Comment: But how would this work when i only want to filter the stamps that belong to a certain place? The stamps node could possibly be full with millions of records. It wouldn't be efficient to retrieve all these records one-by-one right?

Comment: Retrieving multiple items one by one is not as slow as you may think. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786. I also updated my answer with some more info.

Comment: I see, but how can I filter the stamps node but only retrieve the items of the keys that are within the placeStamps node under my place key?

Comment: But what if you have a many to many relation, for example: a user has a lot of stamps and a stamp belongs to one or more users. The date of one stamp changes. Then I would need to update every entry that has the stamp key with the date. (possibly millions of records). How can this be done?

Comment: What you're describing is known as fanning out the data and is a fundamental step in NoSQL data modeling. I covered the approaches to it a while ago in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693785/how-to-write-denormalized-data-in-firebase). I also recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and viewing [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: One last question, how would this work when a device is offline and for example the keys are cached. And you would add a key to the node. The device would not have the new key. So that object won't be updated. This would cause data-inconsistencies.